# Unable to use Auto Config for PyDev interpreter setup

Tags: python, pydev

In setting up PyDev with my Python Interpreter, I select "Auto Config" to bring up a list of directories.  Then press OK, and get an error message:

```
Error: Python stdlib not found or stdlib found without .py files.
```

Apparently, it is looking for files such as threading.py and traceback.py (not just their executables).

And yet, I am able to find both of these files in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`

One of the folders in "Auto Config" folder list is precisely that folder, so I am really lost as to what the problem is.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3 and Python 2.7.3 from python.org.

Comment: what happens if you don't use auto config but specify the path manually?

Comment: Are you sure you're able to find threading.py (and not only threading.pyc) in that folder? Also, is that folder you pointed in the list of folders chosen to be added to the PYTHONPATH during the interpreter configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I also have the same set up you do.

Open your terminal, (in spotlight, just type in "Terminal") and type in "which python". Grab the path that it prints out, go in your configurations but instead of 'Auto Config', click 'New...' and paste the path into the interpreter field.

It'll pull up the same libraries it did with Auto Config, but I think the problem was that autoconfig points to the /usr/lib/... path instead of the new path for the interpreter.

Hope this helps, happy coding!